# What are these slanted surfaces on the bridge saddles of my electric guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, bridge

I randomly took a closer look at the bridge of [my electric guitar](https://www.thomann.de/intl/harley_benton_te_70_rosewood_deluxeb_stock.htm) and noticed that the brass saddles have some weird, flat, slanted surfaces where the strings run over them.

Interestingly, these surfaces are facing in the opposite direction, so not every string runs over them in the same way - some lie flat on the surface, others run right across the sharp edge. Also, the middle saddle is a completely different part (meaning you can't rotate it to look like the other two). Nothing of this seems random, and I suppose it must have a clear purpose of some kind. Anybody knows what it could be?

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: I don't know if someone will find this is a duplicate question, but you might add whether the saddles are actual brass and if that matters in some way.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Product description says brass, so I guess that's what they'll be. Also, duplicate of what, if I may ask?

Comment: your question may be a duplicate of an existing question. I don't know if it is. Many times people spot dups when they themselves have answered the question before.

Comment: It has to be a dup, might be interesting to look at compensated bridges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the saddles are in three pairs like an old Telecaster bridge it looks like the different angles are there so the lower string will automatically have a longer string length. However, like you said, the middle pair is backwards, the D string is shorter than the G. This is intentional. As @ojs said in comments if you use a wound D and an unwound G this would probably work but if you use heavier strings with a wound G this will give you problems so try to stick with unwound G strings. You probably will have to compromise when intonating each pair. Individual saddles are much better for accurate intonation.

This bridge looks like it was designed to improve intonation of the old Tele bridge while still maintaining the three double saddles the original has. The fact that one string goes over the curved part and the other goes over the straight part has no real bearing, the important thing is the location of the high point where the string crosses.

Comment: The middle one has different orientation than others, because the wound D string needs less compensation than unwound G. With wound G, the orientation would be same as the other two.

Comment: @ojs Noted. I checked my guitars with unwound G’s. The D’s and G’s are either the same length or the G’s are slightly longer. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, short and to the point and covers every aspect.

Comment: @MaxD my pleasure. It looks to be a well made bridge and the through body stringing is a nice option. I’m sure with a little patience and effort you can get it intonated pretty well.

Comment: I  agree with the answer, but generally speaking, the B string is longer than the E and the G, which means this guitar is out of intonation, no matter what strings are on it. I filed the saddles on my Tele to enable intonation to work, similar to this bridge - a vast improvement.

Comment: @Tim The G saddle is longer than the B on both of my electrics and in general in my experience. The G saddle can be placed closer than the B if necessary in this case but that would also affect the D string.

Comment: What I meant was that the 2nd string is most often longer (open) than the 1st and 3rd. Hence 'compensating bridges' on fixed bridge guitars. Just checked several of my electrics, and that's the case with them all. On my Tele, I have a similar bridge to the OP's, and had to file the 2nd string saddle to get good intonation between 1st and 2nd, otherwise they'd both be the same open length, and one would always be out.

Comment: @Tim are you by any chance using wound G strings? Do you know the difference between wound and plain string?

Comment: @ojs - I've only played and taught guitar for 60yrs! So I do know the difference. And wound 3rds will need to be longer than plain 3rds, BUT it will also depend on the gauge of them. My go to is generally .012" 3rds, and I don't have wounds on any of my guitars - electric or acoustic.

Comment: @Tim I know. 60 years ago wound 3rds were more popular than now, so I was curious if you use those. In general plain strings need more compensation, i.e. to be longer than wound strings so your guitars are probably set up in some unusual way.